# How to add a dropdown list to each rows with values using jquery datatable in asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to add the dynamic dropdown list to each row when I click the add button and I have written this below code to achieve this and values are coming but not like dropdown list

example code is :-

```
 var ddlInputParameters = $("<select class='input-small' id='ddltype'></select>"); 
$.each(data.d, function (key, value) {

 if (value.Type == "inputparameters") {


                        //var option = $("<option />");
                        var option = $("<option></option>");
                        option.html(value.TypeData);
                        option.val(key);
                        ddlInputParameters.append(option);
                        
                    }

});


//Initially When the page is loaded I'm checking the length and adding the records to jquery table
if ($("#EntryParametersTableDataID,#EntryParametersTableRightDataID tbody").children().children().length == 1) {

var trd = "";
                        trd += "<tr>";
                        //trd += "<td hidden='hidden'><button class = 'btn btn-danger btn-sm'> delete </button></td>";
                        trd += "<td>";
                        //trd += "<select class='input-small' id='ddltype'><option value='1'>Pts</option><option value='2'>%</option></select>";
             trd += ddlInputParameters.html(); //Here I want to add(bind)that dropdown list
                        trd += "</td>";
                        trd += "<td>";
                        trd += "<select class='input-small' id='ddlexit'><option value='1'>None</option><option value='2'>Sq Off Leg</option><option value='3'>Sq Off Strategy</option><option value='4'>Partial Exit</option></select>";
                        trd += "</td>";
                        trd += "<td><input type='text'> </td>";
                        trd += "<td><input type='text'> </td>";
                        trd += "<td><input type='text'> </td>";
                        trd += "<td><input type='text'> </td>";
                        trd += "</tr>";
                        $("#EntryParametersTableRightDataID tbody").append(trd);

 }
```

Output is coming like values not like dropdown list this :-

[image: Coming like a values]

Suggest me where I did the mistake and how can I achieve this.

I'm very new to this jQuery logics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) attribute is not worked in my scenario and I have changed the existing logic like below and it's work well to me

```
var optionsdata = '';

$.each(data.d, function (key, value) {

 if (value.Type == "inputparameters") {


     optionsdata += "<option value="+key+">"+value.TypeData+"</option>";

});

 var ddlInputParameters = "<select class='input-small' id='ddltypeauto'>" + optionsdata + "</select>";
```

And I have added this `ddlInputParameters` to `<td>` like this `trd += ddlInputParameters;`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ddlInputParameters.outerHTML()` instead of `ddlInputParameters.html()` in `trd +=` like below.

```
trd += ddlInputParameters.outerHTML(); //Here I want to add(bind)that dropdown list
```

> The [**outerHTML**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) attribute of the [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) DOM interface gets the serialized HTML fragment describing the element including its descendants. It can also be set to replace the element with nodes parsed from the given string.

Comment: hi @Karan, thanks for your comment and I have added this `ddlInputParameters.outerHTML()` in my code and the total row is skipping. (out put not coming).